# java_language_server installation fails with bash exit code 127

Tags: neovim, lsp

[image]

I have java 17 installed and working and I have successfully installed other LSP servers without any issue.

I have checked and apparently exit code 127 means command not found but that did not help me.

I am on Ubuntu 23 and using neovim.

Comment: There's no question in your question.

Comment: Is `javac` in the path? What is the result of the `javac --version` command?

Comment: Well, it means exactly this, whatever command you are trying to start, is not available. We cannot say more, because it is not clear from your question, what language server you installed and especially not how this is going to be executed. (And this is not really a vi relevant question)

Comment: Ah yes, javac is not in my PATH

Comment: What about it ?

Comment: You have to change the PATH environment variable such that Vim is aware that `javac` is available and knows how to access it.

Comment: I have java, not javac

Comment: I suspect you need `javac` that comes with the [Java JDK](https://www.oracle.com/be/java/technologies/downloads/).

Comment: @samuelnihoul, Did you managed to install the language server? Is the presence of `java` enough to install the language server?

Comment: No I did not and it probably does not. But that is crazy. I will look into javac but I haven't thought I would need it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147177/discussion-between-samuelnihoul-and-vivian-de-smedt).

Comment: Did you solve your installation problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that `javac` is not in the `PATH`.

You can test this by running the following bash command:

```
javac --version
```

To change the `PATH` you have to edit: `~/.bashrc` and the following line:

```
export PATH=path/to/javac:$PATH
```